# Running script through udev rule on Chrome OS

Tags: shell-script, udev, chrome-os

Chrome OS does not natively support LUKS. I have manually installed cryptsetup to Chrome OS (not a chroot environment). It works, I have used it to encrypt a partition on a usb I'd like to use to hold my Keepass database. I have tinkered with udev before and successfully set popper permissions to use ADB/Fastboot without the use of sudo each time. My goal is this:

1. Make a script that executes when my USB is plugged in that unlocks the LUKS partition.
2. Have the script mount the decrypted partition to /media/removable/'USB Drive'
3. Unmount and close LUKS on unplug.

Because Chrome OS is a bit weird and you can't execute programs in userspace normally I put my script in /sbin. Right now it's a simple test script that makes a folder called 'TEST SUCCESS' in my Downloads directory. I have confirmed it works by manually running it. Here is the contents of the 10-local.rules file I have created:

```
chronos@localhost /etc/udev/rules.d $ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules
ACTION="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="****", ATTR{idProduct}=="****", RUN+="/sbin/openKey.sh"
```

**UPDATE:** I'm going to post my short test script in case there is some reason it won't work when triggered by a udev rule even though it works when ran manually.

```
chronos@localhost / $ cat /sbin/openKey.sh
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /home/chronos/user/Downloads/TESTSUCCESS
```

Comment: A shot in the dark: what about fully qualifying `/bin/mkdir`. And a hint: what about making udev log verbosely to see what rules it's considering?

Comment: Thank you very much! Your hint helped greatly! It turns out it was a goof mistake, I guess I'm just to sleepy to work on things right now. I forgot the second '=' on my ACTION command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be nothing more than a simple typo..
`ACTION=="add"` vs `ACTION="add"`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/219928)

Comment: Actually this is my own question, and I do believe it is an answer. Question: What am I do doing wrong? Answer: Typo.

Comment: You can accept your own answer after a day. So you register the problem as solved.